# Display settings problems with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution

For whatever reason (this was working correctly on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) when I try to set my displays on top of each other in the settings, it won't allow to place them on top of each other.

When I click "apply" I get the error message "Could Not Set Configuration Mode for CRTC 63."

Can anybody help me with this? It wont let me set the two displays on top of each other, but it will allow me to place them side to side.

Also, I get a random "Unknown display" as well. This was not existent in 12.04 LTS and I have no idea what it is, seeing as how the only screens that are in use, or plugged up for that matter, is my laptop's display (1366x768) and my Samsung TV display (1360x768) thru HDMI.

Comment: This was also not an issue in Ubuntu 12.10, 13.04 and 13.10. I have used them all. I am facing the same issue in 14.04

Comment: When you say 'on top of each other', you mean your TV display is supposed to be aligned ABOVE your laptop display, so if you move a window upwards, it will cross from the laptop display to the TV? I'm just trying to make sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: Run this command and share the output with us; it will help us figure out what is going on. `$ xrandr`

Answer (score 2):

I found this recent page to be very helpful for 14.04 trusty users:

http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/309-ubuntu-dual-display-monitor-position-lost

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a general problem with placing external monitors above.
I had also seen phanton-screens and error messages like CRTC....
deleting the configuration file ~/.conf/monitors.xml helped me with that.
But now i have another issue with screen ABOVE: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1312342